# Angularjs how to put all urls in one JS page

Tags: angularjs

Here i have soo many factory Pages assiging Urls in Every page is difficulty for me could you  please Help me how can i put all urls at One Place And access in all page Like

```
app.factory('Fac1',function($http){
var hostUrl:'http:loaclhost:4200'
}
```

and second factory is

```
app.factory('Fac2',function($http){
    var hostUrl:'http:loaclhost:4200'
    }
```

soo on 
Please Help me how can i put This **HostUrl** in one Place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use constant variable for your url's.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

in another file you can add all your urls

```
app.constant("urlConstant", {

        Url_Base: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        Url_EmployeeList: 'getEmployeeList'

    });
```

now inject this urlConstant to all your factory just like below

```
app.factory('Fac1',['$http','urlConstant',function($http,urlConstant){

  var hostUrl: urlConstant.Url_Base;
  var getEmployeeListurl: urlConstant.Url_Base + urlConstant.Url_EmployeeList;

}]);
```

Comment: @Rajibul Thank u so much